# Stop character immediately when key is released

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple character controller.

```
void Update () 
{
    var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 6;
    var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 6;

    Vector3 direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(45,Vector3.up) * new Vector3(x, 0, z);

    transform.Translate(direction);
}
```

But this thing has the unwanted effect of speed up and slow down. When I press the button it speeds up to max speed and keeps moving, and when I release it smoothly slows down. But I want it to stop instantly. If I press the button, speed should be the maximum value and `0` when released.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Input.GetAxisRaw`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html) which does not apply smoothing filtering. It should stop right away instead of gradually slowing down.

```
void Update () 
{
    var x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 6;
    var z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 6;

    Vector3 direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(45,Vector3.up) * new Vector3(x, 0, z);

    transform.Translate(direction);
}
```