# Trouble with movement

Tags: c#, game-physics, unity-game-engine

In my game, I have a pacman style arena. Edge colliders are placed over each line. 
Now, for the movement of my player (WASD style), I originally used transform.Translate. This gave me the best fluid motion I would like my player to have. Most of you know, this made the edge colliders ineffective, since the player would just transform it's position right over the edge. To fix this, i used rb.AddForce(new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed); instead, but I really do not like how the player moves with this, since even when you let go of the WSAD keys it still moves and it gives off more of an accelerated move rather than a calculated move.

Does anyone know of a way around this? Fluid WASD movement like transform.Translate but doesn't pass through edge colliders.

I appreciate it!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537362/stop-character-immediately-when-key-is-released/42537458#42537458) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166587/stop-object-instantly-after-collison/43167072#43167072). Both of them describe how to stop your Object when key is released. No that you should never move rigidbody with `transform.Translate`. AddForce or Move function is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your object still moves is the velocity that remains on the rigidbody. My suggestion would be to change the velocity directly. Also, be sure to put your code in FixedUpdate.

```
Vector2 inputVector = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Vertical", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
inputVector = inputVector.normalized; // Makes the Length of the vector = 1 even if pressed diagonally, if you don't want something like this, remove it
rb.velocity = inputVector * speed;
```

For more information be sure to watch this video: https://unity3d.com/earn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/moving-the-player
For more advanced version read this: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=RigidbodyFPSWalker